# How to prove this Mathematical Induction problem?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, induction

We got $n \geq 3$ lines drawn on a surface with conditions below:

1. No two lines are parallel.
2. No three lines make a conjunction in a specific point.

**Prove that one of the areas created by these lines is a triangle.**

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried to prove that we can color all areas made by these line with two colors in a way that no two sides of line have same color. Somehow relating this problem to another one! but didn't work and I think I'm totally wrong. Right now I have no working idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** Suppose the result is true for any collection of $k$ lines in "general" position. We show it is true for $k+1$ lines.

Remove one of the $k+1$ lines, say $\ell$. We now have $k$ lines, and hence a triangle $T$. Now put $\ell$ back. If $\ell$ does not cross $T$, then $\dots$.  And if $\ell$ crosses $T$ then $\dots$.

Comment: Thanks that works. If l does not cross T nothing happens, we already have a triangle and if l crosses T then again we got another triangle (e.g. T') is this what you said?
Could you please update your answer with more explanations? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if does not cross, then we *still* have a triangle, and if it does cross, then we get a new triangle. So in any case there is at least one triangle. I had left this for you to do, and you did it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Do the Induction step.

> Show that if you cut a triangle (infinitely extended) with a line that is not parallel to the 3 sides, nor intersect the vertices, must produce an area that is a triangle.